# How Show Specific No of Post by label in blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

[CARASIA Link](http://www.carasia.in/)
I want to show a 10 post on each label search. but in my website. some label show 10 post and some label show 2 posts I am already trying to show max post by using expr:href='data:label.url + "?max-results=10"'

but in my website { expr:href='data:label.url' }
this code is multiple time written and I am trying to overwrite all that code with the first one. but nothing happens. solve that problem. please?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but you actually may face a Blogger internal limit per single page, which still is 1mb, as far as I'm concerned. If your blog posts heavily depend on photos, the amount of data may be too big to display 10 posts (on rare ocassions you may see only 1-2 posts per page, no matter what Blogger settings are).

Thanks,
Luca